# Many to One Bluetooth Communication Link

Tags: electronics

I have an application that requires data to be streamed from multiple Bluetooth modules to one host controller. Somewhat like multiple Clients and one Server.

The throughput i am looking at is around 1920-bits per second per module. 
The [SPBT2632C2A.AT2](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fweb%2Fen%2Fcatalog%2Fsense_power%2FFM1968%2FCL1976%2FSC1324%2FPF253470&ei=ivZvVbG3DZafugT99oCIBA&usg=AFQjCNE3rd0Y5qAVPf9wHGOxc3klSjLEfg&sig2=kQg3v-7wIdE7NDGiFL688Q&bvm=bv.94911696,d.c2E) module only supports SPP profile in which i can have a single link (One Client One Server). My application needs multiple modules ( Max 5) to send information to one server.

Is there a way to have One Receiving Station and have multiple transmitting module using SPP? (All modules being the SPBT2632C2A), or i need a Different higher end module on the server side which supports multiple SPP Links?

It advisable to look into a module like the BCM2070 and have a driver run system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCM2070 with Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator!

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth protocol allows 3 bit addressing that means you can connect 8 devices. When i did it with neurosky mindwave head sets to computer data streaming was not enough to get raw data. İ can just get one healty data per second from each headset